# how to refresh jquery-ui dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, bookmarklet

I am using jquery,jquery-ui and other libraries, in a bookmarklet.
Only the custom process reside in the bookmarklet. jquery-ui is loaded from an external script, I made a copy on my web storage (just for compatibility reasons).
To do this, I am using a piece of code:

```
function $L(c,f){
    if(window.jQuery)
    {/* mark all previous occurences of this script then remove it*/
        var l=$("script[src^=\""+c+"\"]");
        if(l.length>0)
        {
            var n=l.length;
            for(j=0;j<n;j++)
                l[j].setAttribute("class","__remove");
            $(".__remove").remove();
        }
    }

    var s=document.createElement("script");
    s.addEventListener("load",function(){
        f();
    });
    s.setAttribute("src",c+"?"+timestamp);
    /*document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);*/
    var h=document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    h.insertBefore(s,h.firstChild);
};
```

then:

```
$L(jquery_ui,function(){
    /* do stuff */
});
```

What i'd like to do is the bookmarklet always use the most recent version of jquery-ui in my repository, whenever the user click on the bookmarlet. Not only at the time the page is refreshed or when he went to another page on the site.

The jquery-ui script file on the server is supposed to change for any reason (app upgrading)
Everything goes well, when clicking the bookmarklet, the script is reloaded.
When I modify the jquery-ui file on the server, then clicking on the bookmarklet, the version change. But after a second changement, I am stuck, no version change.

So I guess there is an issue with the variable $ui.
What can I do to avoid this?

Comment: why would you ever need a bookmarklet for script version control? Doesn't seem very user friendly

Comment: my purpose is to use a bookmarklet to do some stuff on any page I can read, like sharing a link with extra info (keywords, images ...).
ALl the functions is in an external script which can be updated on the server. What I want is the bokkmarlet always use the last updated version.

Comment: if only personal use, can use the gitBuild version http://code.jquery.com/ui/

Comment: If I understand correctly, your problems seems to be a problem of caching. The browser is caching the jqui file and either it is not checking your server again or the server is not reporting that the file changed. If I am correct, the problem lies in the headers being sent by your server, not in your javascript. Be aware that any proxies, CDN services, or caching servers you may be using can also be responsible. It is common for them to agressively cache js files.